# SharePoint 2013 IE 11 breaks when accessing sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer

Hi When I try to access my list in IE 11 from SharePoint site. The browser breaks and throws this error. 
[image]

[image]

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Have you tried to run it in a compatibility mode? For more details please check local machine event viewer.

Comment: Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 11.0.9600.18124, time stamp: 0x5641278d
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.DLL, version: 10.0.10240.16390, time stamp: 0x55a5bf73
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0007d84b
Faulting process ID: 0xd90
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1791b2a44b2ae
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase.DLL
Report ID: 698823de-e50e-11e5-8296-d8eb97216422
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Thank you Marek. I have tried compatibility mode. Above is my event log from event viewer.

Comment: Try to run IE without add-ons, maybe it is one of them that is causing issue. Try to run 'iexplore.exe -extoff'

Comment: Thank you Marek, you a star. It was the the add-ons that was causing the issue.

Comment: Glad to help. I added new answer to include compatibility and add-ons check.

Comment: Try other browsers(Chrome and Firefox) unless you really want to use IE.

Answer (score 1):

If you have crashing issues try those: 
1. Run in compatibility mode 
2. Disable add-ons: iexplore.exe -extoff

Answer (score 1):

Looks like disabling add-ons helped you.  For me the specific add-on I had to disable was "SharePoint Export Database Launcher" and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Disabling the "SharePoint Export Database Launcher" did the trick for me. Thanks Kirk.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling add-ons worked, but caused other issues. I found on another site where they stated to run IE as administrator. That is working for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, after installing Office 2016 our users' browsers crash when launching a SharePoint site on SharePoint Foundation 2013. Our browsers did not have the "SharePoint Export Database Launcher" add-on. The event logs show an IE crash / and reference: ucrtbase.DLL.

I also didn't feel rolling back to Office 2013 was a "fix", just a temporary work around.

As of 6/30/16, we're on the latest and greatest Office 2016 release (through Office 365 subscription), and this is still an issue for our users, so Microsoft has not fixed this problem with any recent releases. Maybe there's a patch we just haven't approved yet in WSUS. (yeah, we use WSUS, don't judge me too harshly...)

I wound up troubleshooting this all the way down to the GPO we had in place controlling IE settings for our entire user base.

For anyone that has a similar issue, try this: (this assumes your users access the SharePoint site via your Intranet...)

Open **Group Policy Mgmt**, then edit the policy controlling your IE Settings. Expand **User Configuration**, then **Policies**, then **Administrative Templates**, then **Windows Components**. Next, expand **Internet Explorer**, then **Internet Control Panel**, then **Security Page**, then select **Intranet Zone**. Locate the setting **Turn on Protect Mode**, and set this to **Not Configured**, or **Disabled**. Close Group Policy Mgmt Editor, ensure your policy updates, and force your user(s) to gpupdate. Launch a new IE browser and see if that resolves the issue.

Worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue
**Office 2016 Click To Run 16.0.6528.1017 can crash IE 11 when protected mode is enabled**

**UPDATED on 5/4/2016 ***

**Summary:**

You have Office 2016 Click to Run installed version 16.0.6528.1017 (March 16, 2016 first release channel) or greater and IE11 and your SharePoint side is in an IE security zone that has Protected Mode turned on.

When the above is true and you navigate to some SharePoint web pages (like a list), IE will crash.

**Cause:**

This is a bug.

**Workaround:**

Disable protected mode in the IE security zone.

**Current Status:**

This issue should be resolved in build 16.0.6911.1000 or later of Office.

**Official Technet link** [**here**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2016/04/04/office-2016-click-to-run-16-0-6528-1017-can-crash-ie-11-when-protected-mode-is-enabled/)

Answer (score 0):

Use 64 bit IE for SharePoint sites.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the some great solutions for IE 11 crashes and freezing problem

http://tech.bigpixi.com/internet-explorer-not-working-properly-freeze-crash-problems/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.